# Multiple Libraries Founded Alert and High Cache

Tags: android

I am working on an android app and it started opening late.

```
04-16 18:07:09.834 2683-2683/pp.com.dersProgramim W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
04-16 18:07:23.159 2683-2683/pp.com.dersProgramim D/NotificationMan...: Step 1
```

Here is the logcat in first run. It waits so long to open in "Found Multiple Library tables, ignoring" part. Its like 12 seconds.

After the first run, app makes big size cache and data, like 30 MB.
[App Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Rf3.jpg)

Its so big i think.

And the second run for example, app opens late again in "Found Multiple library tables, ignoring..." part, it waits too, but not as first run, it is 15 ms.

Here is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pp.com.dersProgramim"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "2.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'

    compile project(':BetterPickers')
    compile project(':MaterialDesign')
    compile project(':UpdateChecker')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.1'

    compile 'de.cketti.library.changelog:ckchangelog:1.2.2'

    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'

    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.1.0'

}
```

manifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="pp.com.dersProgramim">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MySchoolSchedule"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/DersProgramimTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/DersProgramimTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|touchscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|stateHidden|adjustPan" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SetSchuleTimeConfigurationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/DersProgramimTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|touchscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|stateHidden|adjustPan"/>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <receiver android:name=".StartReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".NotificationService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And other module's build.gradle files

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta1'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName "1"
        versionCode 1
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

And other one

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

And this is the last

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.5.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDir 'assets'
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, I got this problem too

But the problem solved when I build a released apk.
Maybe you can try to build a released apk.
I guess there might be some problem in the debug apk.

Comment: Thanks. It worked and one more thing, I closed "Instant Run" in Android Studio 2.1 and now it works perfect. Thank you very much.